# Telegram Bot API method kickChatMember ignores until_date parameter?

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

I tried using `kickChatMember` from the Telegram Bot API. In the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#kickchatmember), it is stated this about the `until_date` parameter:

- Type: Integer
- Required: No
- Description: Date when the user will be unbanned, unix time. If user is banned for more than 366 days or less than 30 seconds from the current time they are considered to be banned forever

However, all the calls result in the same **banned forever** status. Looks like this parameter is being ignored, but maybe I'm not understanding something about how parameters work, the date format of something else.

If you want to test this:

1. [Start a conversation with BotFather](http://t.me/botfather), create a new bot and set a name and a handle to get a Bot API key.
2. Create a group and convert it to a supergroup.
3. Add the bot as a group member and grant administrator rights.
4. Add [GroupInfoBot](https://t.me/groupinfobot) to the group to **get the supergroup ID**. Please notice the ID is a negative number, even when this bot tells you it's a positive number, e.g. `-1001935344181`.
5. Tell someone else to join the group for testing purposes.
6. Forward any message from the testing subject to [UserInfoBot](https://t.me/userinfobot) to **get the user ID**.

Then, just use the web browser to send the HTTP API calls. Make sure to change `XXXXXXXXXX:XXXX...` to your Bot API key, `-1001935344181` to your supergroup ID and `999999999` to your testing subject user ID.

All these calls result in a forever ban.

No parameter:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/kickChatMember?chat_id=-1001935344181&user_id=999999999
```

10 days from now:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/kickChatMember?chat_id=-1001935344181&user_id=999999999&until_date=1509090246
```

1 hour from now:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/kickChatMember?chat_id=-1001935344181&user_id=999999999&until_date=1508230000
```

As a workaround, I can call `unbanChatMember` afterwards, but I'd prefer to limit API calls as much as possible.

Comment: Yep, I tested this API, and got same result.